# Deleting the ._* files from a mounted volume kinda screwed some things up

Tags: disk-utility, filesystem, mount, disk-volume

I have a thumb drive that I use frequently, which results in a lot of the `._*` files being created, which I periodically delete by executing something like `find /Volumes/Secure -name '._*' -exec rm -vf {} \;`, and I've never had that ruin anything before. However, it looks like something may have gotten broken during this last execution.

Heres the console output of the `find`/`rm` command:

```
[Tue Aug 14 09:39:12]{1:126}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(✓)$ find -d . -name '._*'
./tor/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/Caches/1blvjd07.default/startupCache/._startupCache.8.little
./tor/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/Caches/1blvjd07.default/safebrowsing/._test-malware-simple.pset
./tor/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/Caches/1blvjd07.default/safebrowsing/._test-phish-simple.pset
./tor/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/Caches/1blvjd07.default/safebrowsing/._test-unwanted-simple.pset
# TRUNCATED
./tor/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/Caches/1blvjd07.default/safebrowsing-to_delete/._test-flashsubdoc-simple.pset
./tor/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/Caches/1blvjd07.default/safebrowsing-to_delete/._testexcept-flashsubdoc-simple.pset
[Tue Aug 14 09:39:18]{1:127}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(✓)$ find -d . -name '._*' -exec rm -vf {} \;
find: .: Invalid argument
```

(Not sure, but maybe it has something to do with the `{}` not being in quotes? I can't remember if I used quotes in the past)

When I mount the volume, I can see the contents just fine as long as I'm not referencing the content using a relative path while I'm in the mounted volume (PWD).

Here's an example of what I mean. You can see that I can list the contents of `/Volumes/Secure` just fine. But if I cd to it, then try to list the content of the current directory, it doesn't work:

```
[Tue Aug 14 09:46:02]{1:193}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes(✓)$ df /Volumes/Secure
Filesystem   512-blocks    Used Available Capacity iused ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk4s1   35372096 1566528  33805568     5%       0     0  100%   /Volumes/Secure
[Tue Aug 14 09:46:06]{1:194}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes(✓)$ ls /Volumes/Secure
chemdocs             credentials          data.tar.gz.enc      scripts              test                 test-data            test-data.tar.gz.enc tor
[Tue Aug 14 09:46:09]{1:195}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes(✓)$ cd /Volumes/Secure
[Tue Aug 14 09:46:11]{1:196}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(✓)$ ls
.
```

Then, just to make this a little more confusing and frustrating, it seems to be intermittent...

```
[Tue Aug 14 09:46:09]{1:195}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes(✓)$ cd /Volumes/Secure
[Tue Aug 14 09:46:11]{1:196}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(✓)$ ls
.
[Tue Aug 14 09:52:28]{1:27}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(✓)$ ls .
.
[Tue Aug 14 09:52:30]{1:28}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(✓)$ ls -alrth .
total 30240
drwxrwxrwx  1 jdoe  staff    16K Jun 18 18:20 .Spotlight-V100
drwxrwxrwx  1 jdoe  staff    16K Jul  3 12:10 test-data
drwxrwxrwx  1 jdoe  staff    16K Jul  3 12:10 .info
# TRUNCATED SOME LINES
drwxrwxrwx  1 jdoe  staff    16K Aug 11 03:41 .Trashes
drwxrwxrwx  1 jdoe  staff    16K Aug 11 03:41 .TemporaryItems
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 jdoe  staff    16K Aug 13 19:22 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 jdoe  staff    16K Aug 14 09:43 .fseventsd
drwxrwxrwt@ 7 root     admin   238B Aug 14 09:43 ..
[Tue Aug 14 09:52:32]{1:29}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(✓)$ ls -alrth ./
ls: ./: Invalid argument
[Tue Aug 14 09:52:34]{1:30}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(0)$ ls -alrth .
ls: .: Invalid argument
[Tue Aug 14 09:52:36]{1:31}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(0)$ ls -alrth .
ls: .: Invalid argument
[Tue Aug 14 09:52:37]{1:32}jdoe@MacBook-Pro:/Volumes/Secure(0)$ ls
.
```

*([Here's a gist with some extra console output](https://gist.github.com/jhyland87/56b5b8e14681bd830db43be6537bec10))*

I've tried unmounting and remounting with no success.

Any input would be appreciated, thank you!

-J

Update
I just noticed something else thats rather interesting... These problems I showed above are all exclusive to the CLI. I can open the mounted drive in Finder and explore it just fine.. Odd.

Comment: The checkmark and the parenthesis are problematic in filenames. The permissions on and in your home folder are to permissive.

Comment: Did you extract your USB key after an `unmount` failed?

Answer (score 2):

The symptoms you describe are the signs of a corupted filesystem, which is the
usual fate of frequently used USB key.

Make a backup of your USB key,
and run an `fsck` or `Disk Utility` on your file-system.

I even advise you to completely check it with:

• full backup,

• full secure erase with one pass of 0 (to be sure to write on all blocks),

• make a new FS,

• recover from backup.

Your `find` doesn't cause any trouble, since `-exec` argument isn't evaluated by a shell, you dont have to protect it against evaluation.

Comment: Can you give some specifics as to what exactly I should execute with `fsck`? I tried to `diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk4s1` with no success, as well as a few other things

Comment: The `-exec` option of `find` does not run the command using the shell, so there is no need to worry about odd filenames. In any case, if you use `"{}"`, the shell will strip the quotes anyway, and `find` will not see them – so using quotes does no harm. If you run the find command from some unusual shell, on the other hand, you may need quotes to stop *that* shell from doing funny things with the braces.

Comment: I updated the original post with some extra info. I noticed that these problems only occur via shell.. I can browse the volume just fine via OSX Finder

Comment: Next important step: what's the result of the `Disk Utility` check?